# Error with Volley Bad URL when getting image

Tags: java, android, image, android-volley

I have some error when I try to load an image from a server using Volley.

This is my log:

```
E/Volley: [31648] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/103.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/103.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/103.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31650] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/106.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/106.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/106.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31651] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/106.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/106.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/106.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31649] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/103.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/103.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/103.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31648] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/0.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/0.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/0.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31650] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/107.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/107.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/107.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31651] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/0.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/0.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/0.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
E/Volley: [31651] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/107.png
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/107.png
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: kinandayu.com/image_content/uploads/107.png
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

This is my Activity.java:

```
public class Child_Tab1 extends Activity {

    List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayaoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://www.kinandayu.com/image_content/getAllImage.php";
    String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "id";
    String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "image";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.child_tab_1);
    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewlayaoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayaoutManager);

    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
    }

    private void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {
    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse (JSONArray response) {
            JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

    GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));
    GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
       }
    }
```

This is my ServerImageParseAdapter.java:

```
public class ServerImageParseAdapter {
    public static ServerImageParseAdapter SIAdapter;
    public static Context context1;
    public RequestQueue requestQueue1;
    public ImageLoader ImageLoader1;
    public Cache cache1;
    public Network networkOBJ;
    LruCache<String, Bitmap> LRUCACHE = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

    private ServerImageParseAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context1 = context;
        this.requestQueue1 = RQ();
        ImageLoader1 = new ImageLoader(requestQueue1, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String URL) {
            return LRUCACHE.get(URL);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            LRUCACHE.put(url,bitmap);
        }
       });
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return ImageLoader1;
    }

    public static ServerImageParseAdapter getInstance(Context SynchronizedContext) {
    if (SIAdapter == null) {
        SIAdapter = new ServerImageParseAdapter(SynchronizedContext);
    }
    return SIAdapter;
    }

    public RequestQueue RQ() {
    if (requestQueue1 == null) {
        cache1 = new DiskBasedCache(context1.getCacheDir());
        networkOBJ = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        requestQueue1 = new RequestQueue(cache1, networkOBJ);
        requestQueue1.start();
    }
    return requestQueue1;
    }
}
```

I'm using compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

The problem is that the image is not shown in my CardView, but the name of `image("id")` is shown.
I've read some questions regarding my same problem, but I don't get any solution.

Comment: `Bad URL kinandayu.com`... You are missing `http://` from that.

Comment: `String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://www.kinandayu.com/image_content/getAllImage.php";` i've already add http:// above @cricket_007

Comment: No, not that... Did you open that address in your browser? Look at the JSON

Comment: @mariomargo try this url : "http://kinandayu.com//image_content//uploads//106.png"

Comment: @DaminiMehra its not found

Comment: Your links work, @mariomargo see `http://kinandayu.com//image_content//uploads//106.png` --> http://kinandayu.com//image_content//uploads//106.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a server-side problem. You need to [fix your PHP & JSON](http://kinandayu.com/image_content/getAllImage.php) to get the correct URL addresses,

```
{
    "id": "106",
    "image": "kinandayu.com\/image_content\/uploads\/103.png"
}
```

If you can't do that, then add `http://` onto the image URL strings.

```
String imgURL = json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL);
if (!imgURL.startsWith("http://") {
    imgURL = "http://"+imgURL;
}
GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(imgURL);
```

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Right... That's what I said. I copied that JSON directly from the URL in the code. http://www.kinandayu.com/image_content/getAllImage.php

Comment: @cricket_007 you're my savior, the image is show up. Thanks for you and everyone in here for answer. I've some little issue maybe in another post question. Thanks again